# python change file names to unicode chars Hindi

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to change the filenames to unicode which i am getting from a file reading line by line. When i try to rename the files, then i gets the error here. Here is the code

```
import codecs
import os

arrayname = []
arrayfile = []
f = codecs.open('E:\\songs.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='r+')

for line in f:
    arrayname.append(line)

for filename in os.listdir("F:\\songs"):
    if filename.endswith(".mp3"):
        arrayfile.append(filename)

for num in range(0,len(arrayname)):
    print "F:\\songs\\" + arrayfile[num]
    os.rename("F:\\songs\\" + arrayfile[num], "F:\\songs\\" + (arrayname[num]))
```

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\read.py", line 25, in <module>
    os.rename("F:\\songs\\" + arrayfile[num], "F:\\songs\\" + (arrayname[num]))
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is in
correct
```

How can change the name of the files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to remove the *newline character* from the end of your lines. Remove it with `str.rstrip()`:

```
for line in f:
    arrayname.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

You can simplify your code somewhat, and use best practices to ensure the file is closed. I'd use the newer (and better engineered) [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) rather than `codecs.open()`. If you use Unicode literals for paths, Python will ensure you get Unicode filenames when listing:

```
import io
import os
import glob

directory = u"F:\\songs"
songs = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, u"*.mp3"))
with io.open('E:\\songs.txt', encoding='utf-8') as newnames:
    for old, new in zip(songs, newnames):
        oldpath = os.path.join(directory, old)
        newpath = os.path.join(directory, new.rstrip('\n'))
        print oldpath
        os.rename(oldpath, newpath)
```

I used the [`glob` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to filter out matching filenames.

Comment: I am new to python & so dont have much practice of it. Thanks for the help